# How does this [].fill.call({ length: 3 }, 4) example work?

Tags: javascript, object, call, fill

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#examples
Example to understand:
[].fill.call({ length: 3 }, 4) //{0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, length: 3}

I think 'length' as a key in an object is somehow special, I can't find a reference for that assertion.
If you use .fill on an empty array it would not modify the array.
So, I don't understand why we are getting this object back.

Comment: `.fill()` modifies `this`. `.call()` modifes `this`. `.fill()` uses `this.length` to determine how many elements it has to "fill"

Comment: Closely related: [What does it mean to use the javascript map function generically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30514225/1048572), [I read in the EcmaScript specification that certain methods are "generic". What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29835765/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's look into the [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method. The first argument `{length: 3}` is the value to use as `this` when calling `fill`.

Then, let's look into the [fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#polyfill) function. When you check the `Polyfill` which explain how the method is implemented, you'll see the following

```
var O = Object(this);
      // Steps 3-5.
var len = O.length >>> 0;
```

so, it use the length of `this` object to decide how to fill the array. As we
already know, `this` now refers to object `{length: 3}`, so `len` equals to 3. Then `fill` function calculates the `finalValue` and add properties to the object, and return the object

```
// Step 12.
while (k < finalValue) {
  O[k] = value;
  k++;
}

// Step 13.
return O;
```

So, you get `{0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, length: 3}`