# Javascript proxy behaves differently on Array.push() and set by index

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a code similar to the following snippet:

```js
let arr = [];
let arr_handlers = {
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
        console.log('setting ' + property + ' for ' + target + ' with value ' + value);

        target[property] = value;
        return true;
    }
};
let arr_proxy = new Proxy(arr, arr_handlers);

arr_proxy.push(1);
// setting 0 for  with value 1
// setting length for 1 with value 1
arr_proxy[1] = 5;
//  setting 1 for 1 with value 5
console.log(arr.length);
// 2
```

The problem is that proxy behaves differently when I use `arr_proxy.push()` and when I set value through index:

Why proxy setter isn't invoked to set length when array value is set by index?

Comment: Your array has only one item, but you're setting an item on index 3.  That converts the array into a sparse array, which doesn't update the length.  I can't find this in the spec though.

Comment: @Amy if I set an item on index 1, it behaves the same way. I've updated the question

Comment: Yeah, my analysis/conclusion was wrong.  I'm not sure.  I'll leave my comment up so someone else doesn't come along and say the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Why proxy setter isn't invoked to set length when array value is set by index?

Because that dynamic `length` property that is special to arrays exists only on the `target`, *inside* your proxy.

In contrast, the `push` method does set the `.length` property on its receiver explicitly. It is not automatically triggered by the assignment to the index. You can try with

```
const obj = { length: 0, push: Array.prototype.push };
obj.push(5)
console.log(obj) // { length: 1, 0: 5 }
```

You can achieve the same behaviour as the `arr_proxy.push(5)` call by writing

```
const _len = arr_proxy.length;
arr_proxy[_len] = 5;
arr_proxy.length = _len + 1;
```

Comment: But the question is _why_ setter is not automatically triggered when assigning to the index? `length` is _special to arrays exists only on the target_ in both cases, do I add value through `push` or through index, but by some reason it is set by wrapper only when assigning through `push()`

Comment: @aryndin Push does not only add the value. Push also explicitly writes to the `.length` property (even if that's unnecessary on array objects, which already will have the right length).

Comment: @aryndin The `length` setter is not triggered during assignment to `[1]` because you're not assigning to `.length`. The `length` *getter* will then recompute the current length afterwards when you *access* the `.length` property.

Comment: isn't `push()` [array prototype specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and thus should take into account that it is not necessary to explicitly set length for arrays?

Comment: @aryndin No, the `push` method [is generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29835765), it doesn't require an array - see the example in my answer with `obj`, which does not have a magic `.length` and still works. (I'm not saying that engines don't implement internal optimisations for `push` when it's called on an array, but it cannot take advantage of them when it's called on an arbitrary proxy object of course). Also notice that `push` needs to be generic to work on your proxy at all, if you tried a proxy around a typed array it would [throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43236329).